# Installing Python 3.11

Tags: python, performance, anaconda, ide, python-3.11

I want to try out Python 3.11 to find out how much faster this version is than what I'm currently using (3.7.3). I am using Anaconda and Spyder, but Anaconda does not yet support Python 3.11 and additionally I regularly have problems with updating in Anaconda.

Importantly, I want to maintain my Anaconda and Spyder environments as it is and use Python 3.11 independently from this. Therefore, I was wondering if simply downloading Python 3.11 from their website will mess up my environment, as then there will be two versions of Python insalled on my PC. Also I would like to know if I have to use a different IDE for this (or even without IDE).

Even though my question might be a bit vague, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to create new env 3.10 using Anaconda, if Anaconda still doesn't have 3.11. The difference with 3.11 would  be (I'm not guaranty, just a "rumors") ~+15%, depends...
2. You can build and install your version from source :
   [build-python-from-source](https://www.build-python-from-source.com/)

This way you won't break anything and can to delete Python3.11 after experiments.

2. You can google the benchmark tests for overage performance comparison between `<your.version>` and `<any.over.version>` for very common understanding.